# С++ Создать в качестве поля одного класса список указателей на объекты другого класса

Tags: c++, классы, list, объекты, объявление

```
#pragma once
#include <list>

ref class ObjectOnMap;

ref class Map
{
private:
    int width;
    int height;
    // Список указателей на объекты. Здесь ошибка "Не допускается использование дескрипторов класса неуправляемый".
    std::list<ObjectOnMap>^ objectsOnMap = new std::list<ObjectOnMap>();
public:
    Map(int width, int height);
    int getWidth();
    int getHeight();
}
```

Мне необходимо одним из полей сделать список указателей на объекты другого класса, однако ни приведенное выше описание, ни описание `std::list<ObjectOnMap> objectsOnMap = new std::list<ObjectOnMap>();`, ни описание     `std::list<ObjectOnMap^> objectsOnMap = new std::list<ObjectOnMap^>();` не приводят к желаемому результату (ошибка "Член класса управляемый не может относиться к типу класса неуправляемый").

Для ясности:

-приведенный код - это код заголовочного файла Map.h

-программа видит класс ObjectOnMap, так как он задан в строке `ref class ObjectOnMap;`, а затем его заголовочный файл подключен в Map.cpp

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как объявить список указателей на объекты правильно.

Comment: ¿Вы случаем не путаете С++ и С++-cli?

Comment: у тебя получился указатель на список обьектов, а надо список указателей на обьекты, поставь std::list<ObjectOnMap*>* objectsOnMap (в случае с++) в заголовке. а потом в конструкторе map выдели память под обьекты

Comment: Aptem_f, ввел, как Вы сказали, ошибка "Не допускается использовать обычные указатели на классы ссылок или классы интерфейсов C++/CLI"